# How to send a response to the invoker of a service without reaching the end of the pipeline

Tags: jboss-esb

I have 2 custom actions exectuting one after the other in the same service like this

```
<actions mep="RequestResponse">
    <action name="ActionA" class="ClassA"/>
    <action name="ActionB" class="ClassB"/>
</actions>
```

Suppose that ActionA does some validations over the received msg. If the validations found that the msg is invalid, how does you send a response to the invoker about that failure?

Right now in my actions I set the response in the message at ActionA and put a mark in it indicating that I found an error in ActionA and ActionB checks for that mark before executing its code. I found this method useful but a burden because all of my actions have to start with:

```
if (!markIspressent) {
    //Code goes here
}
return message.
```

I have tried setting the response msg at ActionA and returning `null` to stop the pipeline but that isn't working. I also tried another method that I found of throwing an `ActionProcessingFaultException(message,"SomeTextGoesInHere")` but that also isn't working.
My main problem with this second one is that the ESB tries to reprocess the msg that thrown that exception and I don't see the response that I set into message until the ESB gives up and sends it back. But that giving up takes up to 60s.

So my question is how can you send a response msg to the invoker before reaching up the end of the service pipeline.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options in finishing earlier the pipeline are:
- return null;
- split the service into three (note service 1 is OneWay and based on your action's results routes to the appropriate service)
Service 1

```
<actions mep="OneWay">
    <action name="ActionA" class="ClassA"/>
    <action name="ActionA1" class="RouteBasedOnMsgContentTo(Service 2 or Service 3)"/>
</actions>
```

Service 2

```
<actions mep="RequestResponse">
    <action name="ActionB" class="ClassB"/>
</actions>
```

Service 3

```
<actions mep="RequestResponse">
    <action name="ActionC" class="ClassC-SimplyRespondsTheProblem"/>
</actions>
```